# Converting from TF 1.x to TF 2.0 keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have a model written in TF 1.x code using tf-slim API as well. Is it possible to convert that to tf.keras in TF 2.0 EXACTLY the way it is? For instance, have exactly the same amount of parameters and training?

In my case, I've tried doing so, but my model in tf.keras actually has about 5% LESS parameters than the one in TF 1.x. I also noticed my model in tf.keras has a much less smooth training stage too. Any thoughts? Thanks

Maybe I'm setting some of the parameters to initialize the layers differently? Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated

This isn't my full model, but I use a lot of the components below:

Original TF.1x model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import slim

def batch_norm_relu(inputs, is_training):
    net = slim.batch_norm(inputs, is_training=is_training)
    net = tf.nn.relu(net)
    return net

def conv2d_transpose(inputs, output_channels, kernel_size):
    upsamp = tf.contrib.slim.conv2d_transpose(
                                                    inputs,
                                                    num_outputs=output_channels,
                                                    kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                                    stride=2,
                                            )
    return upsamp

def conv2d_fixed_padding(inputs, filters, kernel_size, stride, rate):
    net = slim.conv2d(inputs,
                      filters,
                      kernel_size,
                      stride=stride,
                      rate = rate,
                      padding=('SAME' if stride == 1 else 'VALID'),
                      activation_fn=None
                      )
    return net

def block(inputs, filters, is_training, projection_shortcut, stride):
    inputs = batch_norm_relu(inputs, is_training)  
    shortcut = inputs

    if projection_shortcut is not None:
        shortcut = projection_shortcut(inputs)

    conv_k1_s1_r1 = shortcut
    conv_k3_s1_r1 = slim.conv2d(shortcut,
                                  filters,
                                  kernel_size = 3,
                                  stride = 1,
                                  rate = 1,
                                  padding=('SAME' if stride == 1 else 'VALID'),
                                  activation_fn=None
                              )

    conv_k3_s1_r3 = slim.conv2d(shortcut,
                                  filters,
                                  kernel_size = 3,
                                  stride = 1,
                                  rate = 3,
                                  padding=('SAME' if stride == 1 else 'VALID'),
                                  activation_fn=None
                              )

    conv_k3_s1_r5 = slim.conv2d(shortcut,
                                  filters,
                                  kernel_size = 3,
                                  stride = 1,
                                  rate = 5,
                                  padding=('SAME' if stride == 1 else 'VALID'),
                                  activation_fn=None
                              )

    net = conv_k1_s1_r1 + conv_k3_s1_r1 + conv_k3_s1_r3 + conv_k3_s1_r5
    net = batch_norm_relu(net, is_training)
    net = conv2d_fixed_padding(inputs=net, filters=filters, kernel_size=1, stride=1, rate = 1)
    outputs = shortcut + net
    return outputs
```

Attempted TF 2.x.keras model same component:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class BatchNormRelu(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Batch normalization + ReLu"""
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(BatchNormRelu, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.bnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999,
                                                        scale=False)
        self.relu = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()

    def call(self, inputs, is_training):
        x = self.bnorm(inputs, training=is_training)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x

class Conv2DTranspose(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Conv2DTranspose layer"""
    def __init__(self, output_channels, kernel_size, name=None):
        super(Conv2DTranspose, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.tconv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
                                            filters=output_channels,
                                            kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                            strides=2,
                                            padding='same',
                                            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu
                                            )

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.tconv1(inputs)
        return x

class Conv2DFixedPadding(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Conv2D Fixed Padding layer"""
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, stride, rate, name=None):
        super(Conv2DFixedPadding, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 
                           kernel_size, 
                           strides=stride, 
                           dilation_rate=rate,
                           padding=('same' if stride==1 else 'valid'),
                           activation=None
                           )

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        return x

class block(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,
                 filters,
                 stride,
                 projection_shortcut=True,
                 name=None):
        super(block, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.projection_shortcut = projection_shortcut
        self.brelu1 = BatchNormRelu()
        self.brelu2 = BatchNormRelu()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 
                                           kernel_size=3, 
                                           strides=1,
                                           dilation_rate=1,
                                           padding=('same' if stride==1 else 'valid'),
                                           activation=None
                                           )
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,
                                           kernel_size=3, 
                                           strides=1, 
                                           dilation_rate=3,
                                           padding=('same' if stride==1 else 'valid'),
                                           activation=None
                                           )
        self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 
                                           kernel_size=3, 
                                           strides=1, 
                                           dilation_rate=5,
                                           padding=('same' if stride==1 else 'valid'),
                                           activation=None
                                           )
        self.conv4 = Conv2DFixedPadding(filters, 1, 1, 1)
        self.conv_sc = Conv2DFixedPadding(filters, 1, stride, 1)

    def call(self, inputs, is_training):
        x = self.brelu1(inputs, is_training)
        shortcut = x
        if self.projection_shortcut:
            shortcut = self.conv_sc(x)
        conv_k1_s1_r1 = shortcut
        conv_k3_s1_r1 = self.conv1(shortcut)
        conv_k3_s1_r3 = self.conv2(shortcut)
        conv_k3_s1_r5 = self.conv3(shortcut)
        x = conv_k1_s1_r1 + conv_k3_s1_r1 + conv_k3_s1_r3 + conv_k3_s1_r5
        x = self.brelu2(x, is_training)
        x = self.conv4(x)
        outputs = shortcut + x
        return outputs
```

Comment: Please post the code for the models.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Thanks for your comment! I've just edited and added code

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is wrong here; are there any other components that you use? Also, how do you construct the model?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Thanks! I've added the other component that I use. Other than that, it's all the same. Am I using the tf.contrib layers properly? I can't seem to find the default parameters for those